# Is there any keyboard in iOS or macOS that pops up a list of predictions and checks spelling?

Tags: resources

I see it incredibly hard to type in Korean sentences precisely. Especially, I could not differentiate any words from its sound - for example, when I tried to express "I lived in Seoul", I'm going to write:

> 서울에 사라써요.

But the actual spelling is not correct, and I even don't know if it is correct or not in the first place, until and unless I look up for each word and its conjugation in a dictionary, which is a pretty intolerable action IMHO.

So I definitely want a keyboard that automatically pops up a list of prediction and spelling checker (in iOS or macOS). I'm looking for something like the one in English in iOS, but unfortunately the functionality is not available in Korean keyboard...

Comment: Can you use Google Korean keyboard?

Comment: I have just disabled autocorrect on my iPhone because of this. It's so horrible in Korean. The nice thing is that it will still underline words I thinks are misspelled and you can go back and correct them.

Comment: Related side note: I'm also bad at spelling (in English and Korean), but I have recently started using Quizlet/Anki's flashcard feature that lets you hear the words and practice spelling them. It has really helped my Korean spelling, and I also find it way more effective at memorizing the words too. I know you probably weren't looking for someone to tell you, "just learn how to spell correctly," but this has really helped me.

Comment: @ryanbrainard 
I have created a new self Q&A which includes a utility tool for mac users. https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/questions-that-are-lists-of-resources/177#177

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely feel you pain. I did a quick test with my iPhone and it does have some degree of spell correction as it does for English.

But I am not sure how it exactly work. 사라써요 once gave me a good suggestion 살았어요. But I couldn't reproduce it again. 사라써요 however constantly give me 살았어요 which I think is an appropriate suggestion.

[image]

When I checked 사라써요 with [a popular Korean spellchecker](http://speller.cs.pusan.ac.kr/PnuWebSpeller/) that is available free online, it failed to correct it to 살았어요. I guess 사라써요 is probably a bit too ambiguous because 써요 is grammatically correct too.

살아써요 is, however, more obvious that there is one ㅇ missing: 살았(ㅇ)ㅓ요.